# Redisson RRingBuffer capacity cannot be changed dynamically under the same key

Tags: java, redis, redisson

currently I'm working on software where I would like to use Redis to store some data.
Specifically, I would like to use the RRingBuffer where I initially set capacity and it can change during the runtime. My idea was that a new RB is created and the data from oldRB is moved to newRB
For example, maybe this is wrong:

```
    // has some data that is created earlier with a capacity of 4
    final RRingBuffer<String> oldRB = cache.get(SOME_KEY);
    
    log.info(oldRB);

    // new ring buffer with  
    final RRingBuffer<String> newRB = redisson.getRingBuffer(A_NEW_RING_BUFFER);
    newRB.trySetCapacity(3);

    add the data from oldRB to newRB...

    cache.put(SOME_KEY, newRB)
    
    log.info(newRB)
    -------------------------------------------
    CONSOLE:
    info: ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
    info: ["three", "four", "five"]
```

This is initially working but it seems like Redis caches this RB with the initial capacity and cannot change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RRingBuffer.setCapacity()` method added in Redisson 3.13.5. So you can change capacity without buffer state copying.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to write down that I was using 3.13.3.